# How to Get ShiftCode base on time in and time out sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i automatically get Shiftcode based on this tables:

Shift Table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RI5L.png)

Employee In and Out from Biometrics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GfCI.png)

Result Should be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io4Af.png)

Currently to get shift code, timekeeper is manually entering it to the system.

i tried so many sql query specially BETWEEN, but its not working, I hope someone can help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: First, please provide the table schemas and sample data in a readable text format (not images). Next include your attempt and elaborate on "but it's not working". Include your expected results along with the actual results from your attempt, also as readable text.

Comment: Why is this tagged VB.NET and VB6? Seem like a SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(clockInShift.ShiftCode, 'N/A') ShiftCode, clockInShift.TransactionCode, TransactionDate
(SELECT ShiftCode, TransactionCode, TransactionDate
FROM SHIFTTABLE st, BIOMETRICS b  
WHERE
  TransactionFlag = 0 AND
  TransactionTime BETWEEN ShiftIn - 0.5/24.0 AND ShiftIn +0.5/24.0) clockInShift
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ShiftCode, TransactionCode 
FROM SHIFTTABLE st, BIOMETRICS b  
WHERE
  TransactionFlag = 1 AND
  TransactionTime BETWEEN ShiftOut - 0.5/24.0 AND ShiftOut +0.5/24.0) clockOutShift
ON clockInShift.ShiftCode = clockOutShift.ShiftCode AND clockInShift.TransactionCode = clockOutShift.TransactionCode
```

This is without knowing any indecis or anything to make sure its fast enough or what timeframe you're looking for of course.

Comment: Can i ask if  "ShiftIn - 0.5/24.0" is same as shiftin - 'my condition or my timeframe'? Thanks @AngryToddlers

Comment: yeah I was using an example of 30 minutes on either side... it's whatever you need it to be

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work:

```
select 
...
from 
   Shifts sh
   inner join
   Bioms bm
on bm.TransactionDateTime between sh.ShiftIn and coalesce(sh.BreakIn, sh.ShiftOut)
   or 
   bm.TransactionDateTime between coalesce(sh.BreakOut,sh.ShiftIn) and sh.ShiftOut
```